# Split single form into multiple tabs with next/previous button in Yii2

Tags: tabs, yii2, yii2-validation

I want to incorporate tabs in my form(it is dependent on multiple models) with next and previous button, and onclick of these buttons should validate the fields with comes only in their respective tabs but form should be submitted/saved to DB only at the end.

I have gone through my tabs example but they don't seem to have next and previous button in yii2.

Is there anyway to do this??

Comment: you can use form wizard

Comment: yes,  i went through this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-wizardwidget/  but they are using only text in content attribute. what i need is activefields which i am not able to implement

Comment: http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x try using this

Comment: But as I mentioned in my question, i need button like next / previous to navigate between tabs.

Comment: either tabs or wizard is needed but having no luck with both, I had asked another question  regarding wizard here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808416/unable-to-implement-yii2-wizard